# Unwrap optionals of the type Date() from CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, option-type, unwrap

I have created a NSManagedObject sReminderDate: Date(). This is stored in the coreData. The value for this comes from the date and time set by the user from the datePicker.

When the viewcontroller is loaded, this value is compared with the currentDate and time and if the currentTime > sReminderDate then a label says "Time's Up". The issue is that when the user loads the viewcontroller for the first time, the time and date is not set the sReminderDate is 'null'. Hence, it's crashing my app because this is null and I am using it for comparison.

I am having a hard time unwrapping it with if-let and guard statements. Help would be appreciated!

```
let currentDate = NSDate() //Current date and time stored whenever viewcontroller is loaded

if ((currentDate as! Date )  >= (editnotes?.sSelectedDate)! && (editnotes?.sReminderState == true)) //Comparison -> sSelectedDate is the date stored in coreData by the user when scheduling task
{
    editnotes?.sReminderDate = "Time is up"
    reminderMsg.text = editnotes?.sReminderDate
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look what you wanna to achieve is to separate code when you don't have this values and when you got them and can compare, i.e. implement your logic

I'd make something like that:

```
guard let selectedDate = editnotes?.sSelectedDate,
      let needsToRemind = editnotes?.sReminderState else { 
  // implement logic when you DO NOT have values
  return 
}
// Everything is cool and you have values => can compare 
if selectedDate < Date() && needsToRemind {
   editnotes?.sSelectedDate = "Time's up"
   // Possibly editnotes?.sReminderDate better to unwrap somehow
   // if-let, guard-let, ??
   reminderMsg.text = editnotes?.sReminderDate
}
```

Code is much cleaner and more representative

Comment: BINGO! It worked! Thank you so much! Always hate dealing with optionals.

Comment: Just have one more question: In a case where I need to convert sSelectedDate into DateComponents, do I have to unwrap it like above and then implement logic? Cuz I just tried doing that and I am not able to trigger notifications through DataComponents made using sSelectedDate?

Comment: @OsamaNaeem yes, for such conversion you need `Date` type, not `Date?`

Comment: Then why is the DateComponents not working. More info in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244556/how-to-create-datecomponents-from-date-stored-in-coredata

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma (,) as AND operator in swift.

`let currentDate = Date()`

`if let editnotes = editnotes, currentDate  >= editnotes.sSelectedDate!, editnotes.sReminderState == true {
    editnotes?.sReminderDate = "Time is up"
    reminderMsg.text = editnotes?.sReminderDate
}`

- Updated ans

`let currentDate = Date()`

`if let selectedDate = editnotes?.sSelectedDate, let reminderState = editnotes?.sReminderState, currentDate >= selectedDate, reminderState == true {
editnotes?.sReminderDate = "Time is up" reminderMsg.text = editnotes?.sReminderDate
}`

Comment: Still not working. If i am not wrong, shouldn't we be checking id sSelectedDate is nil or not instead of editnotes?

Comment: if your main property `editnotes` is nil, in that case it's property `sSelectedDate` is obviously nil.

Comment: But in coreData, I can have other elements not nil and only one element nil. Is there any way i can check for that?

Comment: firstly have a look at concept of "?" and "!" in swift. In that way you will be more precise to your query. Simply if we are using "?", compiler or relevant will try to fetch the value from it, and if the value is nil, it will just skip that line of code. But in "!", compiler or relevant will forcefully try to get value, and if it's nil, app will crash there.

Comment: Tried it like this: 

` if let datetobecompared = (editnotes?.sSelectedDate) {
            print(datetobecompared)
        }
        else
        {
            print ("nil")
        }`

Comment: `if let selectedDate = editnotes?.sSelectedDate, let reminderState = editnotes?.sReminderState, currentDate  >= selectedDate, reminderState  == true {editnotes?.sReminderDate = "Time is up"
    reminderMsg.text = editnotes?.sReminderDate}`

Comment: Sadly nope! :( It's just not skipping the code if editnotes?.sSelectedDate is nil. No idea what's going wrong.

Comment: what is the type of `sSelectedDate`?

Comment: Date. Bascially I am making a task manager app. The user will select a date for scheduling and that date will be stored in sSelectedDate. Then when the viewcontroller loads, the sSelectedDate will be compared with the currentDate and if sSelectedData <= CurrentDate i will display "Time is up". But since the first time the user hasn't set any time, sSelectedDate will be nil. And thats where I am getting this issue?