# How to create dateComponents from Date stored in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsdatecomponents, usernotifications

I am trying to create dateComponents from Date stored in CoreData from UIDatePicker. However, I am not able to make it. I am first converting Date which is stored in `editnotes?.sSelectedDate` into `dateComponents` and then using the dateComponents for triggering my notifications.

Here is what I am doing:

```
 var date = Date()
        if let editnote = editnotes
        {
           date = editnote.sSelectedDate
        }
        else
        {
            print("nil")
        }
        let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        let unitFlags = Set<Calendar.Component>([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute])
        let anchorComponents = calendar.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: date)
        var dateInfo1 = DateComponents()
        dateInfo1.day = anchorComponents.day
        dateInfo1.month = anchorComponents.month
        dateInfo1.hour = anchorComponents.hour
        dateInfo1.minute = anchorComponents.minute
        dateInfo1.year = anchorComponents.year
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching:dateInfo1, repeats: false)
```

I am doing this:

```
if let editnote = editnotes
        {
           date = editnote.sSelectedDate
        }
        else
        {
            print("nil")
        }
```

to unwrap the optional but it's not working still. Continue reading!

I know I can use anchorComponents but that wasn't working so I copied those into a new DataComponents instance.

I am trying to print the what is stored in`dateInfo1.hour` and I get

> Optional(2)

I reckon this is the reason why dateComponents is not working for triggering notifications at scheduled time. 
Help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Explicit cast it like this

```
let anchorComponents = calendar.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: date) as! DateComponents
```

Comment: can you please elaborate.

Comment: tried that! still not working. Don't think its optional issue tbh. something else is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You'r using `anchorComponents.days / .hours / .days / .minutes` it's all optional. Instead, I'd used initialiser for `DateComponents` where you explicitly set your properties you needed. But I think you'r just doing something wrong and that's why notification not working and the reason is not date. You can simply check it by setting from date to current date plus few seconds to see whether you'll get notification or not